# the first column as "key" then add the rest every column's value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

the first column as "key" then add the rest every column's value

in fact the source data file more that 22 columns

as following only an example:
source file(column delimiter is a space):

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
a 2 3 4
b 3 4 5
```

desired output:

```
a 3 5 7
b 4 6 8
```

val data = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/root/1.txt").getLines

data.toList

how to do next step? thx

Comment: first if you want to use spark, you should use sc.textfile("/root/1.txt") to get an RDD[String], you can read the spark rdd operation doc to understand how to get the desired result: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General algorithm for solving this task:

1. Split each line by separator
2. Group lines by first column
3. Remove first column from each line
4. Transform all strings to numbers
5. Sum lines
6. Print result

With plain Scala:

```
val data = List("a 1 2 3", "b 1 2 3", "a 2 3 4", "b 3 4 5")
data.map(_.split(" ")) // 1
  .groupBy(_.head) // 2
  .mapValues(
    _.map(
      _.tail // 3
        .map(_.toInt)) // 4
      .reduce((a1, a2) => a1.zip(a2).map(tuple => tuple._1 + tuple._2))) // 5
  .foreach(pair => println(s"${pair._1} ${pair._2.mkString(" ")}")) // 6
```